# detach element.download HTML5

Tags: html

in order to make it possible to download a file it can be used HTML5 API:

```
document.getElementById("btn-generate").href = url;
document.getElementById("btn-generate").download = fileName;
```

I want to make an option where a file is not downloadable so I need to detach download property. I was trying by using

```
document.getElementById("btn-generate").href = null;
document.getElementById("btn-generate").download = null;
```

but it is not working as expected...
Anyone knows how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the attribute instead of the property

```
document.getElementById("btn-generate").removeAttribute('download');
```

or do both to be safe.